# How can i compare Input.anyKeyDown to prefab name?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickOnKeys : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;

    void Start()
    {
        prefabs = Resources.LoadAll("Prefabs", typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().ToArray();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

For example i have two prefabs the first prefab name is "Hello" the second prefab name is "World"

I want that if i click on the key H it will do something with the prefab name Hello and if i click on W then to do something with the prefab W

I want to compare the clicked key name to the prefab name.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            if (Input.inputString == prefabs[0].name)
            {
                Instantiate(prefabs[0]);
            }
        }
     }
```